# Rails 4 Posgres sketching out models and relationships. I need advice

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design, model, routes

I'm pretty new to building apps, so I wanted to ask about the best way to build the relationships between these models.

Folders, Albums, Images

I'm using Rails 4 with Postgres:

I'm trying to create photo albums, that can hold multiple images or be empty, to have something added later. The albums could belong to 0 or more folders, and the folders can have 0 or more albums or zero or more images. Images can, belong to a folder, belong to an album, belong to a folder through an album or neither be in a folder or an album. They would all belong to a User.

This is how I have sketched out in my mind. Please let me know what you think:

```
user
has_many :folders, :albums, images

folder
belongs_to :user
has_many :albums, :images

album
belongs_to :user, :folder
has_many :images

images
belongs_to :user, :folder, :albums
```

What I'm confused about is how you say CAN has_many or CAN belong_to, because an image can exist outside of everything except for the user.

Also, what would the routing look like for this. I don't think this would work:

```
resource :user
  resource :folder
    resource :album
      resource :image
```

I have a hard time wrapping my head around what would, once again because everything can exist independently of everything else except the user.

Do I need to have a user_id reference with every item?
Do I need to use any `belongs_to through` in any model?

Thanks for your help?

Answer (score 0):

You can have relationship/association fields that are blank if you have an image or folder that doesn't map to a user. In other words, just because you define a has_many or belongs to relationship you don't necessarily need every image or folder to map to one. The association fields (user_id) can be blank and you can access the records directly.

To access the non-associated images you will need a route not nested under the user resource:

```
get 'images/:id',  :to => 'images#show'
get 'images',      :to => 'images#index'
```

or something like:

```
resources images, :only => [:index, :show]
```

Comment: So, then an image can be independent of any of the other models it belongs to, does this mean my models are probably pretty close to correct? Does that also mean that my routes would work?

Comment: I *think* the routes will work for the nested/associated models but you will probably need to add additional routes to access these outside of the context of a user..

Comment: My intention is to have all the other resources under the context of a user, even the images. The images would need to be outside of folders and albums at times.